# curl issue: same request, different responses

Tags: php, http, curl, guzzle

Here is a problem.

I need to send a request to the API, and get the string from a response.
In this particular case I want to get a string "order already cancelled"

First of all, I checked it in the Postman. It works fine there.
After that, I wrote a php code, using GuzzleHttp package to make a request.
But there I face the problem for the first time.

The response had a header "Content-Length: 4" and seemed like the body was empty.
That was a reason why i got NULL when i tried to call $response->getBody();

Then i ran GuzzleHttp in the debug mode to see the raw http request/response and compare with the Postman.

In general, there were no differences between them, except some unimportant headers like "User-Agent", "Accept-Encoding" and "Postman-Token".

I decided that the problem was with the GuzzleHttp and i rewrote the code with clean built-in curl functions.

```
$basic_auth_base64 = base64_encode("{$this->_http_auth_login}:{$this->_http_auth_pass}");

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "{$this->_base_url}{$uri}?" . http_build_query($params),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Basic $basic_auth_base64",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);        
curl_close($curl);
```

Then I got the same problem! A bad empty response from the API with a headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 4
```

But I need to get a response like:

```
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 23
```

I even checked this request from a bash with curl and it worked fine!

```
curl -X GET \
  'http://website-server.com/api/order/delete/?OrderId=6693' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic base64LoginAndPass' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'User-Agent:' -v
```

I got a good response from the api, so the problem is only with my php code and environment.

Here is the logs from curl. From the bash curl and from the php curl:

**bash curl:**

```
*   Trying 82.236.10.100...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to website-server.com (82.236.10.100) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api/order/delete/?OrderId=6693 HTTP/1.1
> Host: website-server.com
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> Authorization: Basic base64LoginPassword
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx-reuseport/1.13.4
< Date: Fri, 13 Apr 2018 17:04:27 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 23
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=30
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
< 
* Connection #0 to host website-server.com left intact
order already cancelled
```

**php curl:**

```
*   Trying 82.236.10.100...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to website-server.com (82.236.10.100) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api/order/delete/?OrderID=6693 HTTP/1.1
Host: website-server.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Authorization: Basic base64LoginPassword
Cache-Control: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx-reuseport/1.13.4
< Date: Fri, 13 Apr 2018 16:44:59 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 4
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=30
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host website-server.com left intact
```

As you can see, here is a totally identical requests! But different responses!
The main difference is the header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" and the response's body.

What should i do?

Comment: Strange. Do you have access to the server? Try to debug from that side.  Might it be that for the fist call the server answers differently than for consecutive calls. (i.e. after the object been deleted) BTW having `GET` request to delete an object is not the best idea (security wise)

Comment: Oh, of course i agree with you that GET-request is not a good idea to delete an object. But it is not my API and server.

Comment: Thats a problem. What about the guess that it just answers differently according if the object already deleted in the past? Can you rule that out?

Comment: The main magic is that i get 'strange bad response' only from the php-code. When i use the postman, curl or other software everything is all right. It does not depend on amount of requests at all. And in this case, i just need to get a message from the server like "order already cancelled"

Comment: This object #6693 was deleted long time ago and the server must return a message "order already cancelled" for any request. Now I am going to set up a new fake-server to check and compare the real income requests from my clients

Comment: Try to analyze what **really** being sent with tcpdump (or similar tool) for example `sudo tcpdump -vvvs 2048 -l -A host website-server.com` look for the headers and compare two calls. There must be something different between the curl and php call. ( unless its magic :)

Comment: Keep us posted I'm curious what is the problem. Maybe we should take it to chat though..

Comment: I've just checked it with `sudo tcpdump -vvvs`. Here is a result https://imgur.com/a/KF7Re Seems like the requests are identical. It doesn't depend on amount of request, but only the request-place (phpcode / bash curl / postman and etc).................... sht.....

Comment: Wow, it is magic. Just to make sure and clean up the noise a bit can you run `sudo tcpdump -A -s 0 'dst 82.236.10.100 and tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'` and maybe post the text and not picture so it is easier to compare with diff..

Comment: Oh my god.... thanks difftool..... https://imgur.com/a/9ywNh There was a OrderID instead of OrderId

Comment: Lol i just saw that too xDDDD

Comment: I spend all the yesterday for this issue and 4 hours today :D I'm gonna get drunk

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a possible reason, but I 'll try to recommend how to debug.

You are seeing that identical requests produce different results. Now let's make a reasonable assumption: We can be quite sure that the server will return exactly the same result *if* the requests are *really and completely* identical.

So far, you are only *believing* that the queries from PHP and CURL are identical. I am not sure how exactly CURL and PHP CURL write their logs (i.e. I am not sure how and if they can be configured to log *really all* headers).

Notably, it would be interesting to see what headers CURL and PHP CURL are sending with their *request*. I would log the network traffic using tcpdump or Wireshark. I am convinced that the requests will turn out to *not* be identical.

Comment: Thank for your advice. Here is it. I think it _is_ identical https://imgur.com/a/KF7Re

Comment: UPDATE: Actually it wasn't. There was a difference in GET param. OrderID instead of OrderId